# BMW 320i e36 VS BMW 325i e36

Tags: engine, bmw

What are the difference between a **BMW 320i e36** and **BMW 325i e36**, Does the **325** engine offer much more power than the **320** engine, what are the Pros and Cons of each one, Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about maintenance or repair. Instead the OP should simply read the info BMW provide.

Comment: It would help if there was a specific question here.  "Pros and cons" are largely a matter of opinion and could wander into the fit and finish of the cockpit.  This sort of open-ended discussion is welcome in the chat, though.

Comment: @BobCross and@Rory, thanks for your comment, you are right, this is not about maintenance, it should be moved to the Chat rooms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMW_E36), the 320i engine actually displaces 1,991cc, while producing 150hp @ 5900rpm. This engine also produced 140 ft lbs or torque, though from 1991-1994 it did it @ 4700 rpm, and the from 1994-1998 (assuming a midyear engine switch) it produced it @ 4200rpm. It was used in the E36 vehicles from 1991-1998. The 325i engine displaces 2494cc, and produces 192hp @ 5500rpm, so the power occurs sooner without the need for the higher revs (allows engine to last longer producing more horse power - with everything else being equal). It also produces 181 ft lbs of torque, though, like it's 320i brother, it is split from 1991-1993 producing this peak torque @ 4700rpm and from 1993-1995 producing it @ 4200rpm. Both engines are dual overhead cam 6 cylinder engines, sporting 24-valves for ventilation.

What all this is saying is, the 325i has about 28% more horsepower and about 29% more torque. Considering that the vehicles are about the same weight, this is a distinct advantage the 325i has over the 320i. You would definitely be able to feel this by the old seat-of-the-pants meter. There are two main cons to the 325i, those being worse gas mileage and higher cost. Ownership costs (maintenance) should be about the same otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The 320i is 2071cc, whilst the 325i 2495cc. I do not have the performance figures to hand but would imagine that very real and significant differance on the road are not there. In Europe, some vehicles are fitted with slightly bigger engines to accomodate such things as AirCon systems, or, slightly smaller engines to comply with lower taxation charge bands. Maybe there is a BMW fan out there who will expand on this question further.